# Where do you practice your instruments?

Tags: practice, double-bass

I've been playing electric bass and practicing has never been a problem because I could simply use a headphone to practice whenever I wanted. Now I am going to learn double bass, and I see tons of problems ahead.

Acoustic instruments can be very loud and annoying to neighbors. I know I can put a mute on a double bass, but it isn't going to be any better because I rent a room from a large apartment where everyone is very quiet.

How do you find a place to practice? It's been a big problem for me to find a place to practice. I want answers from people who are not students and living in an apartment or sharing a room with others.

Comment: Why not students? I play electric bass and have to check I'm disturbing neither my own housemates, nor the elderly couple that live next door. Can you hear much from other people in the way of TV or music? Would you say your double bass is going to be remarkably loud compared to a normal conversation? (I dislike using headphones as I find them uncomfortable for long practices).

Comment: I said no students because students usually have access to rooms at school for practice. But you are right, I shouldn't need to limit answers only from non-students. My neighbors are extremely quiet, so my bass would be extremely loud compared to their noise.

Comment: You could just use earphones?

Comment: @NeilMeyer A double bass (aka. string bass) is an acoustic instrument and cannot be used with earphones/headphones.

Comment: you can get a cheap used electric upright bass just for practice (around 500$ that's still a lot, but if you can afford it it's a lot quiter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hours you play aren't quiet hours, legally you don't have any problem. Just don't play during night/noon. I've been playing double bass for a couple of years now and no one has ever complained to me for the noise.

No one will complain, unless they are weird.

Comment: I believe I need to do the same as you. I'll talk to my landlord and other tenants in the apartment first.